# How to load ip_vs module successfully?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, linux-kernel, tegra, ipvs

I write the following content to `/etc/modules-load.d/ipvs.conf`

```
ip_vs
ip_vs_rr
ip_vs_wrr
ip_vs_sh
nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

Then I execute `sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service`. However, its error shows,

```
Job for systemd-modules-load.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

Then I run `sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`, the error message shows that

```
...
Failed to find module 'ip_vs_wrr'
Failed to find module 'ip_vs_sh'
...
```

Then I use `modprobe ip_vs_wrr`, it returns the error message,

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_vs_wrr not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.201-tegra
```

I suppose that my system doesn't have `ip_vs_wrr` and `ip_vs_sh` module. My kernel version is `Linux version 4.9.253-tegra` and the system is `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`. How can I load the `ip_vs_wrr` and `ip_vs_sh` module correctly? If I don't load these modules, can I still use kubernets successfully?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you following any tutorial or what? `kube-proxy` by default is run using `iptables`, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies). So if the goal is to run kuberneres cluster on the machine, it's not necessary to have `ipvs`. Moreover, if `ipvs` is requested, but `kube-proxy` doesn't find it, it will start with `iptables` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer to the last question which is directly related to kubernetes:

> If I don't load these modules, can I still use kubernets successfully?

The answer is **yes**, you can use kubernetes.

There are 3 different modes of `kube-proxy` which can be used in kubernetes cluster:

- userspace (legacy, not recommended anymore)
- iptables (default)
- ipvs

By default `iptables` is used. Using `ipvs` is reasonable if there are more than `1000` services within the cluster. For better understanding and comparison, you can read [this article](https://www.tigera.io/blog/comparing-kube-proxy-modes-iptables-or-ipvs/).

If `ipvs` kernel modules are not available, cluster will start in `iptables` mode. This is from [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs):

> Note: To run kube-proxy in IPVS mode, you must make IPVS available on
> the node before starting kube-proxy.
>
> When kube-proxy starts in IPVS proxy mode, it verifies whether IPVS
> kernel modules are available. If the IPVS kernel modules are not
> detected, then kube-proxy falls back to running in iptables proxy
> mode.